# How can have a SQL connection that is sleeping a pending transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, locking

I'm facing some locks at our DB server created by our application. What I don't understand is how a process that is Sleeping is having an Open Transaction (that process 71 is the one creating the Lock).

As far as I know when a process finishes it closes all the opened transactions. Is that rigth?

Thanks in advance mates.

[image]

Comment: See the last field, there you will see "Open Tran(sactions)" set to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I know when a process
>   finishes it closes all the opened
>   transactions. Is that right?

No. If you explicitly open a transaction you must explicitly `commit` or `rollback`. Until that time the transaction remains open so it is perfectly possible for a connection to be idle (not currently processing any task) but still have an uncommitted transaction.

Many people expect that an error will automatically roll back a transaction but this is not the case unless you have

```
set xact_abort on
```

Comment: What if the process hangs or terminates unexpectedly? The transaction remains there forever?

Comment: If the **connection** (i.e. spid) is terminated then the transaction will roll back automatically if there is an error that is not of sufficient severity to terminate the connection then unless `xact_abort` is on the transaction will remain open until the spid is killed in some way.

Comment: This is happening by a client app having an unexpected crash that is creating a lock at the DB. XACT_ABORT looks to work only on errors created by SQL operations, am I rigth?

Comment: -1 because the answer is wrong. If a process terminates with an open connection, that connection is rolled back and closed.

Comment: @erikkallen - Not sure what you mean by process. It's a bit of an overloaded term. Are you referring to spid? In any event the process has not terminated (been killed) it is still alive and well but finished doing any work as can be seen in the OP's screen shot so your comment is at best irrelevant to anything I stated in my answer and at worst wrong. Edit: Though I guess there is also an ambiguity on what is meant by "when a process finishes".

Comment: @Martin: But if the client process disappears, SQL server will find out sooner or later, kill the server process (spid) and rollback the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know when a process
>   finishes it closes all the opened
>   transactions. Is that rigth?

Yes. But it is not guaranteed and you should not rely on it. You must explicitly close the connection.